# "conda install pandas-datareader" not working

Tags: anaconda, conda, python-3.7

I am trying to install pandas_datareader in Anaconda prompt by running the following command as per the official documentation:

```
conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader
```

I am getting the error - "Solving environment : Failed" as shown below

[image]

I am connected to internet.

I found some links which said I needed to downgrade my Conda AND Python versions, so I tried that too, but it again says "Solving environment : Failed"

Also tried running the following command in Anaconda prompt,

```
pip install pandas_datareader
```

and it gave the error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas_datareader (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for pandas_datareader

**Can someone please help here?**

---

### Config Details

1. Conda version : 4.5.12
2. Python version : 3.7
3. OS : Windows 10

Comment: It would be preferable to include all links to documentation/recommendations you are referring to. Are you behind a proxy? [Other Win10 users have reported similar issues](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/764).

Comment: You should create a new, separate environment, don't install packages to the base environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## PyPI Installation

The correct line for installing with PyPI is

```
pip install pandas-datareader
```

Note that the package name uses a hyphen (`pandas-datareader`), which is different from the underscore (`pandas_datareader`) that is used when importing.

## Conda Installation

It's hard to answer this outright without more information.  Other Windows 10 users who are behind proxies have reported the same error on [Issue #764](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/764), which includes potential solutions.

#### Changing Python Version? No

I am skeptical that you would need to *downgrade* Python.  You can easily test whether this is true without having to actually do it. Namely, if you really did need to change your Python version, then the following command would correctly solve the environment:

```
conda create --dry-run -n test-pd-dr anaconda::pandas-datareader
```

whereas this one would fail:

```
conda create --dry-run -n test-pd-dr python=3.7 anaconda::pandas-datareader
```

I expect they'd both fail.  The first one attempts to create any environment with the only constraint being that it include `pandas-datareader`, whereas the second one additionally adds the constraint to use the same Python minor version you report.  If they both fail, it's something else.

Also, changing Python versions is **base** env is risky (it can break your Conda if done incorrectly) and requires following specific directions from Anaconda.

Comment: Thanks! As it turns out, my office firewall was blocking it. I connected the laptop to mobile hotspot and ran this command - pip install pandas-datareader . It worked!

Answer (score -2):

Use the following command in Conda Prompt:

```
conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader
```