# Blocking issue with pandas_datareader in Anaconda - "conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader" not fixing it

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, pandas-datareader

I have a blocking issue with pandas_datareader (Windows) installed with Anaconda/Jupyter. The solutions proposed in other StackOverflow posts are not working as following described.

This is a simple code for testing the datareader package

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader
```

and this is the error I get

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 import numpy as np
----> 3 from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader
 
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'**
```

As suggested in other Q&As here in StackOverflow I manually installed the datareader package with this command

```
conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader
```

The process seemed to be completed successfully; as further verification, if I try to re-install it, I get a notification saying that "# All requested packages already installed."

I have tried to restart the kernel and also rebooted the system. The trouble is still there. I have also uninstalled pandas_datareader  ("conda uninstall pandas-datareader") and reinstaleld it. Nothing. Any idea?

**UPDATE 1**

- "pydoc modules" console command lists the pandas_datareader properly
- "conda list" console command lists the pandas_datareader properly
- in Jupyter the command "help("modules")" **does not** list the pandas_datareader package

and this might be the problem. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a post explaining how to install conda packages in a Jupyter notebook and it seems it has fixed the problem:

```
import sys
!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} pandas-datareader
```

but I don't know why, so if anybody knows what happened and why this fixed the problem, an explanation in the remarks could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this question and the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55038032/conda-install-pandas-datareader-not-working)

Comment: All the environment is under Anaconda; I am not an expert, but I read many posts suggesting to not use and mix pip installations when using Anaconda (remarks were concerning incompatibilities and missing Anaconda advantages). Would you suggest this attempt anyway? Anyway, I launched the first test suggested at the link you wrote keeping the conda installation (no pip one) and I get as result "DryRunExit: Dry run. Exiting." that is ambiguous to me since I cannot understand if the test was or was not successfull.

Comment: Indeed after some research the pip installation might not be the best for you . In a github issue https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/728 they are advising to test if you can import pandas-datareader in the python console, could you try this?

Comment: Because if you are able to use it in the python console but not on jupyter it might be a configuration error between Jupyter and Anaconda

Comment: Right, from python command line I tried "from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader" and get no errors!!!

Comment: but the following answers in that post do not suggest a clear solution. It's very strange since all the other packages have no issues under Jupyter.

Comment: maybe try to use the conda install -c conda-forge pandas-datareader command line? and check with conda list if the pandas-datareader paeckage is present

Comment: Summarizing: we have just tested that it doesn't work over Jupyter, but it seems to be working over the python console. Since it works under the python console I might expect that it is installed. Besides, listing the packages installed in conda I can see pandas-datareader installed: "pandas-datareader 0.10.0 pyhd3eb1b0_0  anaconda". Any idea?